# Firefox browser.tabs.query({}).then() is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

When I do `browser.tabs.query({"currentWindow": true, "active": true}).then(onCall, onError);` or `let querying = browser.tabs.query({"currentWindow": true, "active": true}); querying.then(onCall, onError);` in my addon's background script Firefox complains that

```
Unchecked lastError value: Error: browser.tabs.query(...) is undefined
```

When I replace the same line with the following, it will work as expected, although this is not mentioned in [Firefox API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query):

```
browser.tabs.query({"currentWindow": true, "active": true}, function(tabs){
        onCall(tabs); 
      });
```

My Firefox version is 75.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I had the same issue. Also when I used browser.cookies.getAll().
For me they works just when I use an anonymous func as sec arg. 
But I have the feeling is the way how the code is sturctured the real problem... 
Even tho, I tried to call `await browser.tabs.query({"currentWindow": true, "active": true})` and `browser.tabs.query({"currentWindow": true, "active": true}).then()` or literally copy the Mozilla example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query and no luck in all case..

Answer (score 4):

The `browser.tabs.query()` (and most API under the `browser` namespace) returns a promise. You need to use `await` or `Promise.prototype.then()` to extract a "resolved" value from a promise. For example:

```js
browser.tabs.query({"currentWindow": true, "active": true})
  .then(onCall)
  .catch(onError);
```

Or:

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const tabs = await browser.tabs.query({"currentWindow": true, "active": true});
    onCall(tabs);
  }
  catch(error) {
    onError(error);
  }
})();
```

Please remind that you need to do this for each `Promise` object, for example when you want to use a result from an API as a parameter for a next API call.

```js
(async () => {
  const tabs = await browser.tabs.query({"currentWindow": true, "active": true});
  const tab = await browser.tabs.query(tabs[0].id);
})();
```

FYI, there are more details about `Promise` and async function:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

The callback-based style is available only under the namespace `chrome` - it generally works compatible to Google Chrome's API.

Comment: Actually the callback-based style worked in Firefox and the `.then()` approach did not work. The returned promise is 'undefined'. The thing I tried the first looks exactly the same as your first suggestion, except there is a catch() attached. Does catch change anything here? Otherwise, this does not solve my issue.

Comment: Hmm, do you use any polyfill library like https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill on your addon? Firefox's `browser.tabs.query()` must return a promise always...